Shared Photo Albums are synchronizing blank thumbnails only [solution]
All of my shared albums in Photos.app were suddenly filled with blank thumbnails. And attempting to view each image only revealed a full-sized version of a blank image.
Repairing the .photoslibrary file did not work... nor did rebuilding the .photoslibrary file from scratch. Nor did killing/relaunching the bird process, nor toggling iCloud<>Photos in Preferences (both app and system).
Force-quitting the cloudphotod process and waiting for it to automatically relaunch is what fixed the problem, immediately.
Therefore, rebooting the machine would probably have produced the same result, but that wasn't practical as it would have been more effort to reload/resume work than the above attempts took. Plus I learned a bunch of new stuff. Couldn't find a solution online so I'll post here for others with a similar problem.

The background processes photoanalysisd, photolibraryd, and cloudphotod are not hierarchically run under Photos.app, but independently. So quitting/relaunching Photos.app had no effect.

Side note: I was today years old when I learned that shared photo albums are not structured under iCloud Photos. Rather they function more like the old Photostream [RIP] did, not utilizing personal iCloud storage space.

Thanks for sharing this. The site works better though if the question describes the problem to be solved, and the resolution is posted as an answer below. Can you please edit accordingly?
